# Browser won't redirect to other page with anchor

Tags: html, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony project, where I want to add a link which redirects the user to another page at a specific anchor. The link is dynamically generated:

```
{% if deliveryAddressList is not empty %}
    <a href="{{ path('vendorname_shop_profile') }}#billingAddress">Change billing and delivery addresses</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
{% endif %}
```

The route is:

```
vendorname_shop_profile:
    path: profile
    defaults:
        _controller: VendornameShopBundle:Profile:index
```

If I write the `www.mysite.com/profile#billingAddress` in the browser's URL bar, it works perfectly, but as soo as I click on the link it does nothing.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What does the generated code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out, somewhere in a js file, on the click event on every <a> tag with '#' in it's href attribute, there was a preventDefault()